# java.lang.SecurityException when executing IBM Websphere runmqckm command

Tags: java, security, ibm-mq

I'm trying to setup ssl for IBM MQ server and when I executed the command

`runmqckm -keydb -create -db keydb.kdb -pw password -type cms -expire 1500 -stash`

as one of the steps, it fails with the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:186)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:175)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.security.cmskeystore.FileHeaderHashGeneratorFactory$FileHeaderHashGeneratorV4Impl.generateHash(FileHeaderHashGeneratorFactory.java:145)
    at com.ibm.security.cmskeystore.CMSKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(CMSKeyStoreSpi.java:1206)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1226)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$FileKeyStoreProxy.performLoad(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:304)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$CMSKeyStoreProxy.performLoad(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:437)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$FileKeyStoreProxy.load(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:253)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$AbstractKeyStoreProxy.getKeyStore(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:193)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreItemFactory.getCMSKeyStoreItem(KeyStoreItemFactory.java:323)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreItemFactory.newCMSKeyStoreItem(KeyStoreItemFactory.java:294)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreItemFactory.createKeyStore(KeyStoreItemFactory.java:115)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.CommandFactory$CreateDbCommand.run(CommandFactory.java:402)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.Command.invoke(Command.java:203)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.ikeycmd.main(ikeycmd.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot set up certs for trusted CAs
    at javax.crypto.b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Jurisdiction policy files are not signed by trusted signers!
    at javax.crypto.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b.c(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.b$0.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:333)
    ... 15 more
```

My Websphere and Java version information are as below

**Websphere**

```
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.0.2
Level:       p800-002-150519.TRIAL
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:    
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 801
LicenseType: Production
```

**Java**

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured the solution myself and posting it below for the future reference of other.

1. Download **IBM Unrestricted SDK JCE policy files** from https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=jcesdk.
2. Copy both **local_policy.jar** and **US_export_policy.jar** files to `<mq_installation_path>/java/jre64/jre/lib/security` folder.
3. Give ownership and executable permission of both files to **mqm** user.